# Django not rendering CSS

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to programming and currently Django will not render my CSS. This is the html request

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/blog/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Here's my current set up and what I know to be required for using static files. I don't understand how my paths are wrong if they are?

My current DIR

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

In my settings.py...it is installed.

/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/blog/mysite/mysite/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

along with URL defined

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This is my filepath for my css file

```
/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/blog/mysite/blog/static/blog/main
```

and this is my html header

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">
```

my project urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

my app urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
```

Comment: Do your files have read permissions ? check that once

Comment: How do I check that? I haven't done anything with read permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add something to the answer added by @MohitC, Something that all django beginners face, What's the difference between `STATIC`s , I mean, They are 3

- `STATIC_URL`: This is the url to serve static files
- `STATICFILES_DIRS`: This is **ALL** the places where you'll put static files during development. This has nothing to do with the server setup, This is a django thing.
- `STATIC_ROOT`: This is a place where **ALL** the contents of your **DIRS** in **STATICFILES_DIRS** will be added when you deploy. When we deploy a website, We call collect static and it loops through all the **STATICFILES_DIRS** and copy the content to **STATIC_ROOT** so that the server has only one folder for serving static content and this folder is mapped to the requests that are going to `STATIC_URL` which is `/static/` in our case.

Basically, You are missing `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

There's something I noticed too, I think you're following *Corey Schafer*, The series is great but I have a note, You don't need to include the full app path like `blog.app.BlogConfig`, You can just type in the app name `blog` and it will work as expected, It's easier & More readable.

I'd like to note another thing, If you're a student, Use PyCham. It will make your life easier, It will suggest everything, From app names to string paths to whatever.

Comment: yes! I am following Corey's Django tutorial. In his static file section he did not mention anything about setting up a STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIR...and only showed how to set up the static directories and direct html to it with href. 

Thanks for the clarifications on the 3 types. That makes alot more sense now...and yes, I'm currently using pycharm!

Comment: He'll mention it lately, This is something I didn't understand at the beginning when I watched him, Glad I helped.

Comment: You didn't understand at the time but were you able to render your css?

Comment: Yea I just followed, Everything gets clearer by time

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your settings.py which should point to your staic folder. It is usually done as

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Comment: still get GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/blog/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Update your question with your URL's, BASE_DIR, and path where settings.py is located.

Comment: Update STATICFILES_DIRS  and BASE_DIR code from settings.py as well