# Error deploying Django, unable to configure static files

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tried deploying Django project to www.pythonanywhere.com, My website ran but could not load static files.

I did collectstatic command in hosting server console but got error.

my project file configuration as follows

```
myproject # parent directory
-DjangoApp1 # an app inside project
-Myproject main file(includes manage.py etc)
-DjangoApp2 # an app inside project
-DjangoApp3 (in this app my static files located `DjangoApp3/static/DjangoApp3` )
```

in settings.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/DjangoApp3/static/DjangoApp3/',)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

when I run collectstatic method in local machine ,below error occured

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\DjangoApp3\\static'
```

Comment: Just asking do you have `STATIC_URL`?

Comment: yes I have STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: I have posted an answer try and tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
)
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry still same error occurred  `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\djangorest\\insta\\blogproject\\static`

Comment: take static folder one level up from `DjangoApp3/`

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS should not be the same as STATIC_ROOT

Comment: change `STATIC_ROOT = 'static'` to `STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'`

Comment: `STATIC_URL` should stay the same, `STATICFILES_DIRS` is something else covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433863/django-not-rendering-css/61433968#61433968)

Comment: @Hisham___Pak it worked bro, thanks, now it collected all static files and kept in main file.

Comment: If useful please consider upvoting and accepting as an answer. - Thanks

Comment: Can I keep files as it is and host ? or is it better to delete collected static files and do same in server ?

Comment: Keep as it is better is to host it on s3 bucket or alternate, your statement seems confused.

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I've covered the three in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433863/django-not-rendering-css/61433968#61433968) before

Comment: Nice info on link.